# Keras model for multiclass classification for sentiment analysis with LSTM - how can my model be improved?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, sentiment-analysis

So I want to do predict the number of stars a product gets on Amazon through keras, I have seen other ways of doing this, but I have used the universal sentence encoder with one-hot encoding (I have followed a Youtube tutorial to embed the reviews). Now without using an LSTM layer and using the following layers:

```
`model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=256,input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], ),activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.5))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=128,activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.5))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(0.0001),metrics= ['accuracy'])`
```

I am able to get an accuracy of around 0.55 and a loss of 1, which isn't great. However when I reshape my X_train and X_test data to be 3D input for an LSTM layer and then put it into a model such as:

```
`model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=256,input_shape=(512, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.5))
model.add(keras.layers.Bidirectional(keras.layers.LSTM(100, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.3)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(0.0001),metrics= ['accuracy'])`
```

I get an accuracy of around 0.2 which is even worse, with a loss of close to 2.00.

I have no idea whether an LSTM is necessary as I am new to neural networks but I have been trying to do this for my project.

So I am asking should I stick with the first model without an LSTM or is there a way of changing the second neural network with LSTM to have an accuracy of 0.2 whilst using the embedding methods that I have used?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Why you should choose LSTM instead of normal neurons is because in language, there is a relationship between words and that is important in understanding what the sentence means. The model with only dense layer is not able to do that great because there are no connections it that can store such information, it just predicts by looking at the whole picture and not the connections the words have in between. Coming to LSTM, they stand for Long Short Term Memory, in short, what they have is the capability to remember data that they had seen previously, which helps it in creating connections with different words in the same sentence.

Coming to how you would go about creating your model. First, you need a `Tokenizer` in the TF library to create token out of your data, then convert your sequence into numbers through it, then pad your data using `pad_sequences`. Your data is then ready. In your network, your first layer should be an Embedding layer. Followed by it you can have the LSTM (as I have explained why you should use them) or Bidirectional LSTM (they can learn the dependency from left-to-right and right-to-left, performs better than unidirectional LSTM) or Conv1D (according to filter size it is able model dependencies in lying in its filter length, it has been used and works, you can try) layers, followed by pooling layer (GlobalMaxPooling1D) and then, dense layers to get your predictions.